# Who is this bounty hunter?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

Actually I am not even sure if they are bounty hunter because I do not know who it is... but I ran into this costumed character at Brick Fest of all places...

**Is this a real character in-universe or is this just an awesome fan-made costume?**

I am assuming this is a character from *Star Wars* as he was there with the [501st Legion.](https://www.501st.com/)

[image: bounty hunter in brown and gold costume with big sword]
<sub>Click for full res</sub>

Comment: Why does that have to be a Star Wars bounty hunter and not just a medieval knight?

Comment: Because of Mandalorian helmet?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I will add it to my question but hes was with the 501st.

Comment: The (our) left shoulder has a lion; the right shoulder has a saw blade.   The left side of the helmet looks sort of Mandalorian; the right side doesn't.   There is fur.   I just don't see the evidence this is even supposed to be related to Star Wars.   There are no (metal) swords in Star Wars.   Either it's a weird mashup, or a coincidence.

Comment: There is your answer ^

Comment: Don't even get me started on custom Mandos...They all look like this to me: https://cdn.instructables.com/F2T/XK1W/GFRWNXAZ/F2TXK1WGFRWNXAZ.MEDIUM.jpg

Comment: There are ancient Mandalorian warriors mentioned in Star Wars, like Tarre Visla (the creator of the Darksaber). It looks like this person may have used their imagination to create a suit of armor that might have been.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### This is a fan-made costume.

Designing and wearing custom Mandalorian costumes has been quite popular for years, especially after the Clone Wars series brought in new, canon Mandalorian armor beyond the original Boba/Jango armors from the movies.

While I have no direct evidence, that person is likely a member of the [Mandalorian Mercs](http://mandalorianmercs.org/), a costuming organization that frequently partners with the [501st Legion](https://www.501st.com/) and [Rebel Legion](http://www.rebellegion.com/) to invade sci-fi/comic conventions and perform charity work.

[image]

Most people building Mandalorian armor of that level of detail start off their hobbying at [The Dented Helmet](https://www.thedentedhelmet.com) for resources, guides, and connecting with expert prop-makers. They usually connect with the costuming groups from there or vice versa.

Comment: http://mandalorianmercs.org/forum/index.php?topic=137968.0

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a fan-made costume, based on the helmet looking similar to Boba Fett's, meaning it's probably a medieval version of said bounty hunter.

Not definite, but that's what I see.